# Powershell-File names in a directory with same letters

Tags: file, sorting, powershell, alphabet

I need to write a powershell script, which list file names that contains the same letters, only difference is the sort of the letters.

My first oppinion is to sort the letters in alphabet, and if it fit, then they match, but i need some help for do that

```
Get-ChildItem $path | foreach  {$i=1}`
{  
        $asd=$_ | sort-object
        Get-ChildItem $path | foreach  {$i=1}`
        {  
            $wasd=$_ | sort-object              
            if($asd -eq $wasd)
            {
                Write-Host $_
            }

        }
}
```

This files match for my criteria:
asd.txt, dsa.txt, because contains same letters

Comment: `code`
Get-ChildItem $path | foreach  {$i=1}`
 {  
   $asd=$_ | sort
   Get-ChildItem $path | foreach  {$i=1}`
   {  
    $wasd=$_ | sort 
    Write-Host $wasd "  " $asd
    if($asd -eq $wasd)
    {
     Write-Host $_
    }
   
   }
 }
`code`

This way of sort didnt work

Comment: Get-ChildItem $path | foreach  {$i=1}`
 {  
   $asd=$_ | sort
   Get-ChildItem $path | foreach  {$i=1}`
   {  
    $wasd=$_ | sort 
    Write-Host $wasd "  " $asd
    if($asd -eq $wasd)
    {
     Write-Host $_
    }
   
   }
 }

Comment: Please give examples of the file names that would fit your criteria.

Comment: Put your code in your post, not in a comment. It won't be formatted properly in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is doing what you want.

```
function get-Stringcharacters {
param($string)
  [char[]]$string | sort-object
}

dir $path | group-object @{E={get-Stringcharacters $_.Name}} | 
          where-object {$_.Count -gt 1} | 
          select-object -ExpandProperty Group |
          foreach { write-host $_.Name }
```

Comment: dunno what this doing, but its not working, i need to write-host the file names, who match like i wrote, can u put that to the code?

Comment: Is that closer to what you're looking for?

Comment: still not working, i need the files from $path directory, is that work from that?

Comment: Added $path to the dir cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

gci | % { ($*.BaseName.ToString().toCharArray() | Sort) -join ''} | Group | ? { $*.Count -gt 1 } | Select Name

Comment: it isnt seems like very bad answer, have sense but its not even write anything to my host...